# Bootstrap Non-responsive - Offset keep responsive features

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

When i use [Bootstrap 3 Non-Responsive version](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) the grid keep the responsive features for the offset on browsers lower than @media (min-width: 768px) and that make them disappear and move my layout.

I searched for the issue on the Internet but no one seems to have the problem.

I will keep looking and try to fix it.

Comment: Instead of putting your solution in the question area, please post it as an answer and accept you own answer (checkmark). This will help others that might have this question in the future.

Comment: Oh thanks im new on stackoverflow. I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem (I forgot to add width: 970px !important; to my style.less)

To activate Bootstrap Non-Responsive *as written on bootstrap documentation:

1.- Omit the viewport mentioned in the CSS docs

2.- Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example **width: 970px !important;** Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.

3.- If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.

4.- For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

**.col-xs-offset-*** classes work for non-responsive offset as well.